# How do I configure this Spring project correctly?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat

Me and my team are trying to setup a Spring project, and would like to implement REST services. But when I try to deploy it to tomcat 7, I get an error. Here is the output:

```
Jan 22, 2012 9:39:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Jan 22, 2012 9:39:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:niths' did not find a matching property.
Jan 22, 2012 9:39:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 22, 2012 9:39:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 22, 2012 9:39:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 497 ms
Jan 22, 2012 9:39:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 22, 2012 9:39:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.25
Jan 22, 2012 9:39:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig webConfig
SEVERE: Unable to determine URL for WEB-INF/classes
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Resource /WEB-INF/classes not found
    at org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.listBindings(BaseDirContext.java:733)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.listBindings(ProxyDirContext.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:825)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Jan 22, 2012 9:39:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jan 22, 2012 9:39:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 22, 2012 9:39:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 22, 2012 9:39:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3208 ms
```

I have tried Googling `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Resource /WEB-INF/classes not found` without luck. I am guessing the project was not deployed at all.

The project is hosted on [this GitHub repo](http://github.com/whirlwin/niths).

- [Deployment descriptor](https://github.com/whirlwin/niths/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml)
- [The REST controller](https://github.com/whirlwin/niths/blob/master/src/main/java/no/niths/rest/CourseController.java)

I have added a very simple method for testing my application: `getBaz()`, which I guess would be invoked at `localhost:8080/niths/rest/baz`.

I am having a hard time figuring out what is missing as this is my first Spring project, and would therefore be grateful if someone skilled in the arts of Spring would point out what's the problem!

Comment: How have you deployed it into Tomcat, just put the .war file in? I used the maven jetty plugin to run it -- <plugin><groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId><artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId></plugin> inside pom.xml and mvn jetty:run -- and it appeared to load ok.

Comment: Thanks! This deployed the app, did you by any chance get the so called REST service to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your pom.xml file, it seems that you excluded your classes and libs from the generated war :

```
<warSourceExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/**,WEB-INF/lib/**</warSourceExcludes>
```

Try again by removing this line.

Comment: It still displays `javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Resource /WEB-INF/classes not found`, even after I completely removed the project, re-downloaded it, and tried again.

Comment: The error you are observing seems to a problem in Tomcat 7.0.25 [issue 52511](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52511). Found via [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9261392/12039).