# Tomcat 7 in Eclipse Indigo: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Resource /WEB-INF/classes not found

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to configure Tomcat 7 in Eclipse Indigo, i added the Tomcat plugin from http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html#A3 into **eclipse\plugins** folder. 
Now when i start tomcat i am getting the below error:

```
    Feb 13, 2012 4:23:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig webConfig
SEVERE: Unable to determine URL for WEB-INF/classes
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Resource /WEB-INF/classes not found
    at org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.listBindings(BaseDirContext.java:733)
    at org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.listBindings(ProxyDirContext.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:825)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:897)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:873)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Feb 13, 2012 4:23:35 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

Comment: Why are you using a 3rd party Tomcat plugin instead of Eclipse's own one? Are you using "Eclipse for Java" or "Eclipse for Java **EE**"?

Comment: i Installed Eclipse for Java EE, in that in the server tab i added the server , when i run the server and try to open the http://localhost:8080/ in the browser, it did not give me the welcome page, therefore i added the plugin in the eclipse plugins, now it gives me the welcome page in browser but adding to that it gives above error in console.

Answer (score 10):

```
SEVERE: Unable to determine URL for WEB-INF/classes
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Resource /WEB-INF/classes not found
```

This is actually a bug in Tomcat 7.0.25 and fixed in Tomcat 7.0.26. See also [issue 52511](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52511). Please note that you can just **continue** using your web application! This log is purely informal and does not block Tomcat from starting and functioning. It's caused by a change in the way how Tomcat scans annotated classes. This stacktrace will be printed when you don't have any classes in your Eclipse project and hence the `/WEB-INF/classes` remains empty.

Upgrading to Tomcat 7.0.26 will hide this log. You can also just ignore it altogether and continue using Tomcat as usual.

As per the comments,

> *i Installed Eclipse for Java EE, in that in the server tab i added the server , when i run the server and try to open the localhost:8080 in the browser, it did not give me the welcome page, therefore i added the plugin in the eclipse plugins, now it gives me the welcome page in browser but adding to that it gives above error in console.*

What did it give instead? A server-specific 404 error page or a browser specific "Connection timeout" page? If 404, then the server runs **perfectly fine**, it's just the URL which did not point *anything*. Note that Eclipse does by default *not* deploy Tomcat's own homepage, simply because that's not useful at all while developing. It will only deploy Tomcat's own homepage when you configure Eclipse to take over Tomcat installation instead of using its engine:

[image]

You need to let the URL point to the real URL of the deployed web project. It defaults to the project name which is configureable in project's properties. If the project name is for example "Playground", then you need to open http://localhost:8080/Playground instead. If you want to have it on domain root, then you need to change the *Context root* in *Web Project Settings* to `/`:

[image]

Last but not least, I recommend to remove that Sysdeo plugin which you installed without any necessary reason. It is not in any way better than the Eclipse-builtin plugin.

#### See also:

- [Tomcat started in Eclipse but unable to connect to http://localhost:8085/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280064/tomcat-started-in-eclipse-but-unable-to-connect-to-link-to-http-localhost8085)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i made the above changes, and now able to see the tomcat home page. But i am getting the below error in the eclipse console, My workspace has got no new project created, it just has the default one that comes with the tomcat installation in the webapps directory.

SEVERE: Unable to determine URL for WEB-INF/classes
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Resource /WEB-INF/classes not found
 at org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.listBindings