# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Resource /WEB-INF/classes not found with maven tomcat plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

i am running on **maven 2** and i am using the **Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin for tomcat 7**
with the following configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
    <configuration>
      <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
    </configuration>       
</plugin>
```

but when trying to run the application with **mvn tomcat7:run**
i am getting the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Unable to determine URL for WEB-INF/classes
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Resource /WEB-INF/classes not found
        at org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.listBindings(BaseDirContext.java:733)
        at org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.listBindings(ProxyDirContext.java:546)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1197)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:825)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5161)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

please advise how to fix this exception.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is a problem in the tomcat version bundled with the tomcat7-maven-plugin (which is [fixed to 7.0.25](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/maven-plugin/tags/tomcat-maven-plugin-2.0-beta-1/pom.xml?view=markup#l69)). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9261392/12039) on a similar question.